# .NET 8 MAUI and In-App purchase not getting list of consumables

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

In my .NET 8 MAUI app, I'd like to add some *in-app purchase* for all the platforms. I'm starting to implement the version of Windows to understand how it works.

I follow this [documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/) for the NuGet package called [InAppBillingPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin), design by James Montemagno also for MAUI.

In the Windows Store, I created 2 new add-ons

[image]

The names of the add-ons are *LifePackage1* and *LifePackage2*.

Following the documentation, I added in my code the function to retrieve the items from the store.

```
public async Task GetItems()
{
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
    billing.InTestingMode = true;

    try
    {
        string[] productIds = { };

        #if WINDOWS
        productIds = new string[] { "LifePackage1", "LifePackage2" };
        #endif

        //You must connect
        var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

        if (!connected)
        {
            //Couldn't connect
            return;
        }

        //check purchases
        var items = await billing.GetProductInfoAsync(
                                      ItemType.InAppPurchaseConsumable, productIds);
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException pEx)
    {
        //Handle IAP Billing Exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Something has gone wrong
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }
}
```

I saw that James in the [source code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/580) of his app is using the names of the add-ons. Debugging the code, it runs the line where it gets the `GetProductInfoAsync` but the list is empty.

[image]

Any idea what I have to change?